# How to create a List of lists from a specified number of models/classes?

Tags: c#, reflection

Well, the titled of this question/doubt I think it is pretty self-explanatory, but here go the idea (Using simple terms):
I have Files (In a project) that contain a class (each one of 'em) which has objects and methods (From Models), and one of these methods returns a List. I wanna create another class to generate a new List that will contain all those lists mentioned above. If this is possible mainly in C#, I would appreciate your points of views in how to create this. Thanks in advance for tips, helps and good intentions!!!

I hope you can understand me, because I'm very bad in describing problems. :D

Comment: It would clarify if you showed the relevant classes, lists, and methods, with some sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is SelectMany:

```
#region Terrible Object

var hasAllTheItems =
        new[]
        {
                new[]
                {
                        new
                        {
                                Name = "Test"
                        }
                },
                new[]
                {
                        new
                        {
                                Name = "Test2"
                        },
                        new
                        {
                                Name = "Test3"
                        }
                }
        };

#endregion Terrible Object

var a = hasAllTheItems.Select(x => x.Select(y => y.Name));
var b = hasAllTheItems.SelectMany(x => x.Select(y => y.Name));
var c = hasAllTheItems.Select(x => x.SelectMany(y => y.Name));
var d = hasAllTheItems.SelectMany(x => x.SelectMany(y => y.Name));

Assert.AreEqual(2, a.Count());
Assert.AreEqual(3, b.Count());
Assert.AreEqual(2, c.Count());
Assert.AreEqual(14, d.Count());
```

`A: {{Test}, {Test2, Test3}}`

`B: {Test, Test2, Test3}`

`C: {{T, e, s, t}, {T, e, s, t, 2, T, e, s, t, 3}}`

`D: {T, e, s, t, T, e, s, t, 2, T, e, s, t, 3}`

Comment: hm this is new to me. I've never faced with this situation before. Can I ask you where you based from to get this idea?

Comment: Basically, hasAllTheItems is a collection of collections of generic items containing strings. Select builds a collection of items based on each item in that collection, as in A. In B, SelectMany is used to specify that you want each individual element, rather than one list per inner object.